# How to change the data model of the QSqlQueryModel's subclass at run time?

Tags: c++, sql, qt, qml

Can I manage `QSqlQueryModel`'s subclass at run time calling its methods from QML code and updating (changing) the current model? (The data is send to `TableView` ) How can I do it?

**My `QSqlQueryModel`'s subclass:**

```
class SqlQueryModel : public QSqlQueryModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit SqlQueryModel(QObject *parent = 0);

    void setQuery(const QString &query, const QSqlDatabase &db = QSqlDatabase());
    void setQuery(const QSqlQuery &query);

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const;
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const {  return m_roleNames; }

private:
    void generateRoleNames();
    QHash<int, QByteArray> m_roleNames;
};
```

**main.cpp:**

```
// ...
SqlQueryModel sqlQueryModel;
QQuickView view;
QQmlContext *context = view.rootContext();
context->setContextProperty("sqlQueryModel", &sqlQueryModel);
// ...
```

---

For example, I need to call `Q_INVOKABLE` method `changeModel()` at run time that changes the current model and updates it with parameterized `SELECT` query:

```
void SqlQueryModel::changeModel(const int someValue)
{
    QString statement;
    QSqlQuery query;

    statement = "SELECT * FROM 'tablename' WHERE some_field = ?;";
    query.prepare(statement);
    query.addBindValue(someValue);
    query.exec();

    setQuery(query);
}
```

And as result we get update the data into `TableView`:

```
TableView {
    id: view
    model: sqlQueryModel

    TableViewColumn {
        title: "1st field"
        role: "someValue"
        delegate: Text {
            text: styleData.value
        }
    }

    TableViewColumn {
        title: "2nd field"
        role: "oneMoreValue"
        delegate: Text {
            text: styleData.value
        }
    }
}

// ...
    onSomeSignal: {
        // query like this:
        sqlQueryModel.changeModel(someValue);
    }
```

Is it possible to do it using `QSqlQueryModel`? Please help me to solve this problem.

**UPD:** Perhaps, it's necessary to call function like `qmlRegisterType()` in order to allow using `Q_INVOKABLE` methods of `SqlQueryModel` class from the outside (from QML) and then initialize `SqlQueryModel` *as a type* within QML file. Thereafter we can connect our new `SqlQueryModel` *type* as `TableView`'s data `model`.

**UPD:** I don't need to edit the data stored in the database. I want to be able to change `SELECT` query from one to similar.

Comment: Read documentation. No you can't modify data in `QSqlQueryModel`.
Please remember that `QSqlQueryModel` is ued to disblay response of query. 
`QSqlQueryModel` can't analyze this sql query to figure out how to update database. 

You as a programmer have knowledge how to properly update database and you have to use this knowledge so your application could performs updates on this kind of databases.

Comment: @MarekR, I don't want to modify data and update data in the database, I only need to change "select" query from one to another (both are addressed to the same table). The result of this query includes the same columns and their roles. Why can't I do this using QSqlQueryModel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very strange but the right answer is in the question.

The implementation described there works correctly. Perhaps, it went badly because of typo or defect that sneaked into project's source code.